# View the list of links into page with mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
var lstName = new List<string>();
lstName.Add("<a data-toggle=collapse data-parent=#accordion href=#User1>link-1 </a>");
lstName.Add("<a data-toggle=collapse data-parent=#accordion href=#User2>link-2 </a>");
lstName.Add("<a data-toggle=collapse data-parent=#accordion href=#User3>link-3 </a>");
var names = string.Join(" ، ", lstName);
```

for display :

```
<p style="font-size: 20px; color: #d51818;">@names </p>
```

Why links are displayed as a string? How do I display them as links?

Comment: In mvc you dont need to create html strings in controller side. You just pass your data, and create them in view side.

Comment: have you tried @html.Raw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use MvcHtmlString as type of your html strings, because MVC encodes ordinar strings automatically.
So rewrite your code in this manner:

```
var names = new MvcHtmlString(string.Join(" ، ", lstName));
```